# Make my website logo adapt different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I'm currently building a website (wesurf.co.il) and I'm having some trouble with the logo part. Im trying to make the logo stay on the left side ( next to the central menu).
while on 1920x1080 it looks good, in other resolution's the logo just blend with the menu or dissapearing. 
thanks for helping.

Comment: you need a media query for that

Answer (score 1):

http://prntscr.com/l3zprs you can set it like this change css for `<a> </a>` and `<img/>`

Comment: I want to make the logo seperate from the menu stuff, so it will be next to it from th left, not inside of it like in your screenshot

Comment: then you can set it using `position:absolute`

Comment: yeah I used the css option and wrote this :".logo-img{
     float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
  top: 55px;
}"

but it still changes in different resolutions :<

Comment: put your `<div class="logo-img">` into body directly and add `position:relative` to `body` tag and also you need to change size of the logo when window size is change

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it will help :

```
<div style="display:flex; align-items: center; background:#888;">
  <div class="logo-img"> logo </div>
  <div class="menu" style="margin:auto;"> menu </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS. Also, you should use a SVG logo so it can scale on any device.

```
.logo-img {
    width: 100%;
}
#header .nav-main.boxed{
    max-width: 843px;
}
#header .logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 873px);
}
```